# Search box is not attaching to Google Map

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to add a Search Box with Google Map. But it is not attaching to Google Map. Here is my code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  initMap();
});

$(document).on('change', '#search', function() {
  var id = $(this).val();
  initMap(id);
});


function initMap(id = '') {
  if (id == 'volvo') {
    // Specify the center of the map and other options
    var mapOptions = {
      center: {
        lat: 40.7128,
        lng: -74.0060
      }, // New York City coordinates
      zoom: 12
    };

    // Create a new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    // Specify the center and radius of the circle
    var circleOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: {
        lat: 40.7128,
        lng: -74.0060
      }, // Same as the map center for this example
      radius: 10000 // Radius in meters (10 kilometers in this example)
    };

    // Create the circle
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);
  } else {

    // Specify the center of the map and other options
    var mapOptions = {
      center: {
        lat: 51.5072,
        lng: 0.1276
      },
      zoom: 12
    };

    // Create a new map
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);

    // Specify the center and radius of the circle
    var circleOptions = {
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillColor: '#FF0000',
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      center: {
        lat: 51.5072,
        lng: 0.1276
      }, // Same as the map center for this example
      radius: 10000 // Radius in meters (10 kilometers in this example)
    };

    // Create the circle
    var circle = new google.maps.Circle(circleOptions);

  }





  // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
  const input = document.getElementById("pac-input");
  const searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);

  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);
  // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
  map.addListener("bounds_changed", () => {
    searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
  });

  let markers = [];

  // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
  // more details for that place.
  searchBox.addListener("places_changed", () => {
    const places = searchBox.getPlaces();

    if (places.length == 0) {
      return;
    }

    // Clear out the old markers.
    markers.forEach((marker) => {
      marker.setMap(null);
    });
    markers = [];

    // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
    const bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    places.forEach((place) => {
      if (!place.geometry || !place.geometry.location) {
        console.log("Returned place contains no geometry");
        return;
      }

      const icon = {
        url: place.icon,
        size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
        origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
        anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
        scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25),
      };

      // Create a marker for each place.
      markers.push(
        new google.maps.Marker({
          map,
          icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location,
        }),
      );
      if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        // Only geocodes have viewport.
        bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
      } else {
        bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
      }
    });
    map.fitBounds(bounds);
  });



}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=APIKey&libraries=places" defer></script>

<input id="pac-input" class="controls" type="text" placeholder="Search Box">
<div id="map" style="height: 400px; width: 100%;"></div>
<select id="search">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I suggest you read https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/load-maps-js-api and use a callback instead of the "document ready" method.